# Помогите сделать проверку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходима выполнить разрешение на ввод только типов данных(str), если ввели даные другого типа, вызвать соответствующее сообщение.

Comment: приведите пример своего собственного кода, а что не получится, с тем поможем

Comment: Если вы под вводом имеете в виду `input()`, то **любые** входные данные имеют тип `str`. Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

При команде  `name = input()`
Переменная `name` будет по умолчанию типа `str`.

Если нужно проверить какого типа переменная то можно сделать так:

```py
test_str = type(name)
if test_str == "<class 'str'>":  
......  
else:  
......
```

Comment: работает только вариант else

Comment: Обязательно нужно создать новую переменную `test_str`. Что бы она значение `<'class 'str'>` воспринимала как  текст. На прямую `if type(name) == "<class 'str'>"` не работает